# Food Across CA-US Border

Tags: usa, canada, food-and-drink, land-borders

I am travelling via Greyhound through the border at Windsor/Detroit. I plan on bringing a sandwich, some fruit, and non-alcoholic drinks with me on the bus. Will I be able to take them through?

Comment: is it a beef sandwich? Also, are you going into Canada or into the USA?

Comment: If heading into the states leave the fruit behind or eat it before crossing.

Comment: I don't think the beverages will be a problem.  You could double-check by calling Greyhound.  (I think the reason for the fruit potentially being a problem is the risk of spreading farm pathogens.)

Answer (score 4):

Food that is clearly intended for your consumption, like a sandwich, is almost always allowed across the border both ways. However fruit has been prohibited in some people's experience, even if it's a couple of pieces. My advice would be to pack something other than fruit.

The worst case scenario is confiscation. I've never heard of anything worse happening.

Comment: during the mad cow situation roast beef sandwiches were being confiscated.

Comment: You can get a fine if it something that is banned in the US, like Kinder Surprise, or Irn Bru.